# Returning types from mapped types depending on argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to return the value of a mapped type from a generic function based on an argument, the type seems to be correctly detected on calling but it's reporting error on the return.

I'm not considering using overload on `genericFunction` as `E` could have more than 100 values on my use case.

```js
enum E {
  e1="e1",
  e2="e2"
}

interface E1Payload {
  payloadFrom1: string
  anotherField: number
}

interface E2Payload {
  payloadFrom2: string
}

type Mapping = {
  [E.e1]: E1Payload
  [E.e2]: E2Payload
}

function genericFunction<K extends keyof Mapping>(e: K): Mapping[K] {
  if (e === E.e1) {
    // ERROR: Type '{ payloadFrom1: string; anotherField: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Mapping[K]'.
    // Type '{ payloadFrom1: string; anotherField: number; }' is not assignable to type 'E1Payload & E2Payload'.
    // Property 'payloadFrom2' is missing in type '{ payloadFrom1: string; anotherField: number; }' but required in type 'E2Payload'.
    return {
      payloadFrom1: "e1",
      anotherField: 2
    }
  }
  // ERROR: Type '{ payloadFrom2: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Mapping[K]'.
  // Type '{ payloadFrom2: string; }' is not assignable to type 'E1Payload & E2Payload'.
  // Type '{ payloadFrom2: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'E1Payload': payloadFrom1, anotherField
  return {
    payloadFrom2: "e2"
  }
}

// This work correctly
const payloadE1: E1Payload = genericFunction(E.e1)
const payloadE2: E2Payload = genericFunction(E.e2)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAolDeBYAUFKwCMBeARJnANCmsAEy5k4oC+KKAliAC7ABOAZgIYDGwsGABU4BPADYB7TgBMExKAAcRE6QDFW4iBgBcUAM5NWjAOZzOIcUwAWbFfWCipO8BABGbGnWSMWHHnxikQmKSMkioCkohahqkOvqGICbItMgoTMLyfACynPLyxlBYsuEA2jAAdJgAujowgpHScmWVpDWwgQ1SHqnI7GAg3Ez04iBQRqBs9Nwq-YPDIAA8ANLoAB4sIFK6UADWwMLi7FA5ecYAfAAUwDpLAJQ6J-mJJUtVxWj0R1eFWEUVmLd3mgoAB6EGwABKEIA8hCdAAVDJ8ADk8AiwVU6k0cQMxgA3FAzBZrKxbPZHFBnG5WATqMioPRtuYmITdLp6EYQJwXKI+ExxFB0pkoMjHsYXlVkeU5GgwVBEcLUejlFJoti9LjEgSiVYbHYHE5INTafTGZSLKz2ZzubzBQKhSi6kEVVAAGTtZ0hKUy0HggTqTKsdIixQY1VY0im7YQRnsxIM0YOkVo0MqtXaDUJIza5kkskGylGtgmqAuMAs1jAACOYHolZkjEFSJFAU90m94TQlaYYFYozCwOBqaiWIzeAwhB9aB1ef1FNIPpSaCXvshMLh8ubSuHmJiOKzJbNzMtHK5PL59q3Yuerw7svBCpRKc6atimfxUDpDKZFs4bNPNoXk2ipOp0boep0d6ro+ybKiOe7vlqn5RlAMb-vGupQOw4iiBIADuBTyAGbBDMA2zsFiwGOvUYbIjoO7hhoGAEISuZ6uScjdr2-Y+gxr46HgpBUOEKQpCgcrwpYZp4eIrA7FA3CyZWgyiMIKCKSA+hwdIdS1DRLpFOMICTNMsxDCMFz-BgtzqSMWkMQEtQdGGhRjBMhimQM5kgJZLS3EAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by rewriting `genericFunction` to contain a map-like structure:

```
function genericFunction<K extends keyof Mapping>(e: K): Mapping[K] {
  return {
    [E.e1]: {
      payloadFrom1: "e1",
      anotherField: 2
    },
    [E.e2]: {
      payloadFrom2: "e2"
    }
  }[e]
}
```

For more complex scenarios, I would advise using a type assertion. TypeScript can not really narrow down generic types. That's why it can not understand the `if/else` narrowing you are doing here.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAolDeBYAUFKwCMBeARJnANCmsAEy5k4oC%20KKAliAC7ABOAZgIYDGwsGABU4BPADYB7TgBMExKAAcRE6QDFW4iBgBcUAM5NWjAOZzOIcUwAWbFfWCipO8BABGbGnWSMWHHnxikQmKSMkioCkohahqkOvqGICbItMgoTMLyfACynPLyxlBYsuEA2jAAdJgAujowgpHScmWVpDWwgQ1SHqnI7GAg3Ez04iBQRqBs9Nwq-YPDIAA8ANLoAB4sIFK6UADWwMLi7FA5ecYAfAAUwDpLAJQ6J-mJJUtVxWiswExgrKNhaGhmtUdP8AWhFMFVOpNDo8BhCHIwWYLNZWLZ7I4oKREVBqERwoCKmQ2qCwRDlFJohBYlA8KQqATcXJqCVgFVuigAPScqAAFUs9G2AHdxKwdlBuKLPoNRMIUJKQPoIpCpHVavUVYUxhNDNNZkMRhciRhbvKRkrySEArUOpqiuMQJM9QMDSAjS1bkA)